# I want to stop nohup script

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle12c

I've started nohup command to delete 1 month worth of data:

```
Nohup sqlplus username/password@sidname  @/home/month.sql
```

After deleting some 10 days of data from that script, I want to stop the nohup script, or I want to keep the remaining 20 days of data as it is.

Please help with this

Answer (score 0):

- If you know the PID of the script, then kill -9 PID.
- else find the PID first by using ps -ef | grep "Nohup sqlplus", then kill -9 PID.

Comment: If I'm deleting 2 month data by 2 different script on same db by using nohup sqlplus,

Comment: On different path of same db,  then how to check that pid,  actually I'm getting only 1 pid for the same but I run 2 script on different path of same db

Comment: when you say two script, u can get the scripts PID by using below command, pid=$$ it will be unique PID specific to script.